# sqoop export --update-key from hdfs to mssql

Tags: sql-server, export, sqoop

I require to do a sqoop export with update-key to update a table in mircosoft sql.

I have a hive table that I can successfully export to a mssql table:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:sqlserver://{some.ip.address};database={somedatabase} / --username 'someuser' /
--password-file '/some/password/file' /
--table 'Sometable' /
--columns ID,value1,value2 /
--export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/some.db/Sometable /
--input-fields-terminated-by "||" / -m 2 /
/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/sqljdbc4.jar
```

However, i wish to update on a key and run:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:sqlserver://{some.ip.address};database={somedatabase} /
    --username 'someuser' /
    --password-file '/some/password/file' /
    --table 'Sometable' /
    --columns ID,value1,value2 /
    --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/some.db/Sometable /
    --input-fields-terminated-by "||" /
    --update-key ID /
    --update-mode allowinsert /
    -m 2 /
    /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/sqljdbc4.jar
```

The logs are very unhelpful, (note: the sqoop is run through an oozie job):

```
...
5972 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl  - Submitted application application_1485423751090_3566
6016 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - The url to track the job: http://had003.headquarters.7layer.net:8088/proxy/application_1485423751090_3566/
6016 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - The url to track the job: http://had003.headquarters.7layer.net:8088/proxy/application_1485423751090_3566/
6017 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Running job: job_1485423751090_3566
6017 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Running job: job_1485423751090_3566
20284 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1485423751090_3566 running in uber mode : false
20284 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1485423751090_3566 running in uber mode : false
20287 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 0% reduce 0%
20287 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 0% reduce 0%
27001 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 50% reduce 0%
27001 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 50% reduce 0%
Heart beat
37117 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 0%
37117 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  -  map 100% reduce 0%
38139 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1485423751090_3566 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1485423751090_3566_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0


38139 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Job job_1485423751090_3566 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1485423751090_3566_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0


38292 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Counters: 32
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=338177
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=166
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=4
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=2
        Other local map tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=16369
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=16369
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=16369
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=25142784
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=0
        Map output records=0
        Input split bytes=156
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=79
        CPU time spent (ms)=960
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=230920192
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3235606528
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=162529280
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
38292 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  - Counters: 32
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=338177
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=166
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=4
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=2
        Other local map tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=16369
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=16369
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=16369
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=25142784
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=0
        Map output records=0
        Input split bytes=156
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=79
        CPU time spent (ms)=960
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=230920192
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3235606528
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=162529280
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
38319 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Transferred 166 bytes in 34.0574 seconds (4.8741 bytes/sec)
38319 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Transferred 166 bytes in 34.0574 seconds (4.8741 bytes/sec)
38332 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Exported 0 records.
38332 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Exported 0 records.
38332 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Export job failed!
38332 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase  - Export job failed!
38333 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool  - Error during export: Export job failed!
38333 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool  - Error during export: Export job failed!


<<< Invocation of Sqoop command completed <<<


 Hadoop Job IDs executed by Sqoop: job_1485423751090_3566


Intercepting System.exit(1)


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<


Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]


Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully


Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://{Something}
38406 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory  - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
38407 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool  - Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]


Oozie Launcher ends


38538 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task:attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
38538 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task:attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
38601 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
38601 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
38641 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter  - Saved output of task 'attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0' to hdfs://{Something}
38692 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task 'attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0' done.
38692 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task  - Task 'attempt_1485423751090_3565_m_000000_0' done.
```

Does anyone have an idea why I cannot update with inserts to mssql? Is it not supported? An I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**`--update-mode allowinsert`** could be a culprit here.

As per the documentation:

> Depending on the target database, you may also specify the `--update-mode` argument with `allowinsert` mode if you want to update rows if they exist in the database already or insert rows if they do not exist yet.

To achieve this, Sqoop is using

```
 INSERT INTO … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

So this **upsert** feature (*this kind of query*) is not supported by all the RDBMS.

Check more about [upsert in sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_upsert_functionality).

Comment: Hi dev, Thanks for your answer. I am using sqoop 1.4.6 and in the release note [link](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/sqoop-1.4.6.releasenotes.html) it says it supports it:
New features:
SQOOP-1403 Upsert export for SQL Server

Comment: @antipko thank you for the reference. Can you add `--verbose` to the your sqoop command to check extended logs. Nothing can be concluded from the current logs.